# How to change javascript keyword in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I would like to change JavaScript `function` keyword to `ƒ`.

Example:

```
const doSomething = ƒ (arg) { ... }
```

Is there any way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can write a Babel plugin that will transpile your "f-script" into regular JavaScript.

Comment: and then expect that all the JavaScript intellisense still works. Nope. Maybe you can setup a Font Ligature (file contains `function` but editor shows `f`)

Comment: @rioV8 yes I would like just to change Font Ligature, so the IntelliSense still can work

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your helpful comments.
In the end I've came up with this solution:

[image]

I've combined [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) font ligature with [vsc-conceal](https://github.com/Pancaek/vsc-conceal) extension.

Code represented in image:

```
const doSomething = function (arg) {
  return arg * 2;
};

const doSomething2 = (a, b) => {
  if (a != b) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: My answer is just a dummy code representing the solution. @ShambhavGautam

Comment: But the point of this question was not about code but the code editor. If I've posted the code instead of the image I would've shown nothing. @ShambhavGautam

Comment: @IlijvaIvic Okay sorry.

Comment: @IlijvaIvic I thought you made it so hat f is a keyword. Like operator overloading in C++. The function syntax that you used is very  similar to that in operator overloading and as my eyes blur out while seeing dark magic functional JavaScript, I got confused. It's still good to have the text version as well.